# Calculate p-value between two lists of floats of unequal size

Tags: statistics, variance, python, p-value

I would like to calculate the degree of variance between to lists of floats of unequal size expressed in a p-value.

I tried a two-sided t-test as in the example below using python. But answers that don't use python are just as welcome!

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
import numpy as np

# len(list1) = 324
list1 = list(np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=8.25266, size=(324,)))

# len(list2) = 2954
list2 = list(np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=7.12928, size=(2954,)))

ttest_ind(list1, list2)
```

```
Out[1]: Ttest_indResult(statistic=2.584318054915878, pvalue=0.0098000615059825)
```

But as you see already the p-value between two randomly generated lists of floats is always statistically significant. So my question is: Is a two-sided t-test the right way to calculate statistical significance between two sets of floats of unequal size and if not what would be more appropriate?

Comment: You need to use the F-test.

Comment: You are checking whether $\sigma_1 ^2 = \sigma_2 ^2$ against an alternate hypothesis right?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not an experienced statistician nor a mathematician but rather a biologist. Hopefully you are able to explain your answer such that I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion!